# JVM crashing while writing to Excel file(POI) with Java 8

Tags: java, crash, apache-poi, jvm-crash

I am getting JVM crash issue frequently while trying to write to the Excel file.I am using Apache POI 3.12 and Java 8 and Tomcat Server.
I get the following hs_err_pid error:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f16e02d1ec0, pid=1135, tid=0x00007f1595ef8700
    #
    # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_352-b08) (build 1.8.0_352-8u352-ga-1~18.04-b08)
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.352-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libzip.so+0x4ec0]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

------
Stack: [0x00007f1595df8000,0x00007f1595ef9000],  sp=0x00007f1595ef5900,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libzip.so+0x4ec0]
C  [libzip.so+0x5b6e]
C  [libzip.so+0x3b25]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getEntry+0x85
J 91  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(J[BZ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f16cd13ea8e [0x00007f16cd13e9c0+0xce]
J 123871 C2 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream; (304 bytes) @ 0x00007f16d6716944 [0x00007f16d67165c0+0x384]
J 124037 C2 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getInputStream()Ljava/io/InputStream; (44 bytes) @ 0x00007f16cda4bd00 [0x00007f16cda4bc60+0xa0]
J 103326 C1 org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.<init>(Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage;)V (212 bytes) @ 0x00007f16d6af7374 [0x00007f16d6af6300+0x1074]
J 100022 C1 org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties()Lorg/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties; (40 bytes) @ 0x00007f16cd79ddfc [0x00007f16cd79dce0+0x11c]
J 67174 C1 org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V (35 bytes) @ 0x00007f16cd89404c [0x00007f16cd893a80+0x5cc]
J 65014 C1 com.bulk.helper.ExcelUtility.saveWorkBook(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (89 bytes) @ 0x00007f16cd543754 [0x00007f16cd542ea0+0x8b4]
J 71211 C1 com.bulk.helper.ExcelAccess.save_userfile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (14 bytes) @ 0x00007f16ce6e46ec [0x00007f16ce6e4640+0xac]
J 93237 C1
```

The following is the code:

```
Calling class:
accessFile.save_newFile(---);

Common Method Class:

    @Override
    public void save_userfile(String filePath , String fileName) {
       utility.saveWorkBook(userWorkbook,filePath,fileName);
    }

    public void saveWorkBook(Workbook workbook ,String filePath, String fileName){
        try
        {
            File directory = new File(filePath);
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }
            File file = new File(directory,fileName);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            workbook.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error(Constants.ERROR_STRING,e);
        }
    }
```

I am aware of the solution of putting "-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true" parameter.

Enabling this option will impact performance because the VM will have to conduct some additional disk IO every time it reads an entry from a JAR file (to interrogate the central directory structure).

Want to solve this issue programmatically in java 8 itself.

Any help will be appreciated,Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should report it at http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp as the message mentioned

Comment: Actually ... it will most likely be closed as a duplicate or "won't fix".

Comment: [Apache POI 3.12 was released in 2015](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.12), Java 8 in 2014 and is EOL. What happens if you upgrade to something vaguely recent and still supported?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is any solution in Java 8 other the one you have already mentioned; i.e. disabling memory mapping.

However if you look at the various JDK bug reports for native code crashes in `getEntry`, they are marked as "resolved in Java 9".  So upgrading to Java 11 is a possible solution.

In Java 9 they have replaced the native implementation of `ZipFile` with a pure Java implementation.

For reference, here are some of related Java bug reports against Java 8 and earlier versions:

- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8142508
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8144958
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8145260
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7142247